# BlueSky Statistics - Character Encoding Problem

Tags: r, character-encoding, spss, iso

I am loading a data set, characters of which was encoded in ISO 8859-9 ("Latin 5") using Windows 10 OS (Microsoft has assigned code page 28599 a.k.a. Windows-28599 to ISO-8859-9 in Windows).
The data set is originally in Excel.

Whenever I run an analysis, or any operation with a variable name containing a character specific to this code page (ISO 8859-9), I get an error like:

```
Error: undefined columns selected
BSkyFreqResults <- BSkyFrequency(vars = c("MesleÄŸi"), data = Turnudep_raw_data_5)
Error: object 'BSkyFreqResults' not found
BSkyFormat(BSkyFreqResults)
```

The characters ÄŸ within "MesleÄŸi" are originally one character in Turkish (g with an inverted hat on) ğ

Those variable names that contain only letters from US code page work normally in BlueSky operations.

If I try to use save as in Excel and use web option UTF-8, to convert the data to UTF-8, this does not work either.  If I export it to csv file, it does not work as is, or saved as UTF-8.

How can I load this data into BlueSky so that it works?

This same data set works in Rstudio:

```
> Sys.getlocale('LC_CTYPE')
[1] "Turkish_Turkey.1254"
```

And also in SPSS:
Language is set to Unicode
[Picture of Language settings in SPSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWYUB.jpg)

It also works in Jamovi

***I also get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0SUe.jpg) when I start BlueSky, that may be relevant to this problem:***

Python-CFFI error

```
From cffi callback <function _consolewrite_ex at 0x000002A36B441F78>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rpy2\rinterface_lib\callbacks.py", line 132, in _consolewrite_ex
  File "rpy2\rinterface_lib\conversion.py", line 133, in _cchar_to_str_with_maxlen
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 15: invalid start byte
```

Since then I re-downloaded and re-installed BlueSky, but I still get this Python-CFFI error every time I start the software.

I want to work with BlueSky and will appreciate any help in resolving this problem.
Thanks in advance

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awvw1djaatqasnh/MinimumReproducible.zip?dl=0) for reproducing the problem.

The zip file contains a data source of 2 cases both in Excel and BlueSky format, a BlueSky Markdown file to show how the error is produced and an RMarkdown file for redundancy (probably useless).

**UPDATE:** The Python error (Python-CFFI error) appears to be related to the Region settings in Windows.

If the region is USA ([Turnudep_reprex_Windows_Region_USA-Settings.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8IeK.jpg)) , the python error does **NOT** appear.
If the region is Turkey ([Turnudep_reprex_Windows_Region_Turkey-Settings.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPCOm.jpg)) the python error **DOES** appear.

Unfortunately, setting the region and language to USA does eliminate the python error message **but not** the other problem.  Still all the operations with the Turkish variable names end up with an error.

This may be a problem only the BlueSky developers may solve ...

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE FOR VERSION 10.2:** The Python error (Python-CFFI error) is eliminated in this version.  All others persist.  I also notice that I can not change the variable names that have characters not in US code page.  Meaning, if a variable name is something like "HastaNo", I can do analysis with that variable and change the name of the variable in the editor.  If the variable name is something like "Mesleği" I can not do analysis with that variable AND I CANNOT CHANGE THAT NAME in the editor to "Meslegi" or anything else, so that it is usable in analysis.

**UPDATE FOR VERSION: BlueSky Statistics Version 10.2.1, R package version 8.70**
No change from Version 10.2.  Variable names that contain a character outside of ASCII, cause an error AND can not be changed in BlueSky Statistics.

**UPDATE FOR VERSION: BlueSky Statistics Version 10.3.2**

I also posted this as an answer below, as it solves the question / problem that I originally posted.

I have recently received an e-mail from the support group of BlueSky Statistics (support@blueskystatistics.com) informing me of a new version (10.3.2) with support for Turkish characters in the data.
Long story short, this version works without throwing errors and actually solves the queries posed. I understand they also worked to solve problems with Chinese, French and Portuguese. This is a public announcement of my thanks. I know this is volunteer work. It is very much appreciated, I am sure Chinese, French and Portuguese will also appreciate your kind efforts. Thank you very much BlueSky Statistics support team. Also when I asked about progress on this issue earlier, I had a response ending like this: "...however we need to look at this further. Please give us a couple of weeks as we look at potential solutions. Sincerely Aaron Founder, BlueSky Statistics" I was and I am very deeply impressed that the founder was taking a personal interest in user problems, to the extent that he answered them personally. Thank you very much Aaron. I sincerely hope I helped your wonderful software be used by more people, by helping you address these usability problems. There is still a small step for improvement, if you wish: the variable names that contain offending characters, are currently replaced by their ASCII lookalikes (like g instead of ğ etc.). This is not a show stopper, not even a big deal. If you wish to make another step forward this may be it. Making the variable names work as they are in these languages.

THIS ISSUE IS NOW OFFICALLY SOLVED

Thank you very very much, keep up the wonderful work.

**FURTHER UPDATE FOR VERSION: BlueSky Statistics Version 10.3.2**

I said: "variable names that contain offending characters, are currently replaced by their ASCII lookalikes (like g instead of ğ etc.)."  This is only so IF YOU HAVE NOT SET YOUR LOCALE via the settings as illustrated below in the figure (courtesy of BlueSky Statistics Support):
[How to set the locale in BlueSky Statistics via Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm766.jpg)

If you do these settings correctly, your variable names will appear exactly as you wrote them in your local characters:
[Variable name in local characters: Doğum_yılı](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C28zD.jpg)

If not, your variable names will look like written in ASCII but still your data will be in local characters AND the software will work and produce results without throwing errors.
[Variable name in ASCII characters: Dogum_yili](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n4mo.jpg)

I think this is awesome. Well done BlueSky Support, I stand corrected.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might help you to play around with the examples in `?Encoding`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. Your first example is flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Proof in Python: `'Mesleği'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1254')` results to `'MesleÄŸi'`. Solution:  read the `csv` file using proper encoding `utf-8`…

Comment: JozefZ, thank you very much for your time and effort.  I did try to put a minimal reproducible example.  I do understand how the problem looks initially.  But in BlueSky all visible characters look normal (ğ looks like ğ and not ÄŸ.  When I do an operation however, BlueSky throws an error, and within the error message I see the replaced characters.  It may have to do with the Python-CFFI error maybe?

Comment: @Mikael Jagan, thank you for taking the time and helpful suggestion.  I did follow your lead and learned some, but ultimately I could not resolve the problem.

Comment: @Phil thank you very much for editing and clarifying my post.  This is very helpful.  Thank you sir.  I removed Rstudio from tags as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently received an e-mail from the support group of BlueSky Statistics (support@blueskystatistics.com) informing me of a new version (10.3.2) with support for Turkish characters in the data.
Long story short, this version works without throwing errors and actually solves the queries posed.  I understand they also worked to solve problems with Chinese, French and Portuguese.  This is a public announcement of my thanks.  I know this is volunteer work.  It is very much appreciated, I am sure Chinese, French and Portuguese will also appreciate your kind efforts.  Thank you very much BlueSky Statistics support team.
Also when I asked about progress on this issue earlier, I had a response ending like this:
"...however we need to look at this further. Please give us a couple of weeks as we look at potential solutions.
Sincerely
Aaron
Founder, BlueSky Statistics"
I was and I am very deeply impressed that the founder was taking a personal interest in user problems, to the extent that he answered them personally.  Thank you very much Aaron.
I sincerely hope I helped your wonderful software be used by more people, by helping you address these usability problems.
There is still a small step for improvement, if you wish: the variable names that contain offending characters, are currently replaced by their ASCII lookalikes (like g instead of ğ etc.).  This is not a show stopper, not even a big deal.  If you wish to make another step forward this may be it.  Making the variable names work as they are in these languages.

THIS ISSUE IS NOW OFFICALLY SOLVED

Thank you very very much,  keep up the wonderful work.

Answer (score 0):

For version 10, according to user manual chapter 15.1.3 you can adjust the encoding setting. (answer has been edited for more clarity)

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: The user manual appears to be an evolving document.  I had downloaded BlueSky Statistics Version 10 User Guide (Beta 2 Edition) November 2, 2021.  Part 15 in this document is Glossary.  A word search for "encoding" does not yield anything about character encoding.

Comment: @Anonymous: The current version at this time (Version 10.2 - September 26, 2022) does not appear to be downloadable. Chapter 15 is about Agreement. There is no 15.1.3. I appreciate your help but if you please go the extra mile and tell the name of the chapter and section heading, I will appreciate it very much. Thank you.

Comment: @Anonymous: It's a new version (10.2.1) and I can still not find "the encoding setting"; can you please tell us where it is?  A link to the guidebook section or any kind of help to show us where this setting is in the software?  I did not find it in settings, and I do not know where else it can be.  I did not find it in the guidebook.  Please help.